# Django query set filter reverse startswith on charfield

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filters

Image some kind of product-rule which has 2 conditions:

- name are equal
- sku's have partial match, starts with.

The rule model looks like this:

```
class CreateAndAssignRule(models.Model):
    name_equals = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sku_starts_with = models.CharField(max_length=100
```

Now I want to fetch all of the rules with name `Product 1` and match sku `sku-b-292`

```
class CreateAndAssignRuleQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def filter_by_name_and_sku(self, name, sku):
        # We're looking which of the rules have a matching name, and where the rule have a string which is the string of the sku provided.
        rules = self.filter(name_equals=name)

        approved_ids = []
        for rule in rules:
            # We're looping through the rules to find out which of them has the beginnings of the sku.
            # a sku_starts_with field would contains value eg: 'sku-a' where as the search string would be the full sku 'sku-a-111'.  We want to match 'sku-a-111' but not 'sku-b-222'.
            if sku.startswith(rule.sku_starts_with):
                approved.append(rule.id)

        return self.filter(id__in=approved_ids)
```

although the above works, it's hardly efficient especially as the number of rule is starting to grow a lot.

How can I resolve this with a queryset?  Filtering on `__startswith` doesn't do the trick as it the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

class CreateAndAssignRuleQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def filter_by_name_and_sku(self, name, sku):
        return self.alias(
            sku=Value(sku)
        ).filter(
            name_equals=name,
            sku__startswith=F('sku_starts_with')
        )
```

We thus here inject the `sku` in the queryset, and then use this to work with a [**`__startswith`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#startswith).